Makeindex lost some pages when using custom schem
For a booklet of songs, I have created a custom numbering schems for indexing.
Using indtl@wrindexentry, I can refer to song number in .idx
The .idx file looks like this.
\indexentry{Frère Jacques}{C1}
\indexentry{Frère Jacques}{C2}
\indexentry{Frère Jacques}{C3}

But, when running makeindex, I get
  \item Frère Jacques, C3

So I lost C1 and C2.
Using idx file looking like this
\indexentry{Frère Jacques}{C-1}
\indexentry{Frère Jacques}{C-2}
\indexentry{Frère Jacques}{C-3}

I correctly get
  \item Frère Jacques, C-1--C-3

But that is not I want.
How to do without the middle dash ?
If you want to produce such .idx and .ind file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indextools}
\makeindex[name=main,title=Main Index]
\begin{document}
Some text
\makeatletter
\indtl@wrindexentry{main}{Frère Jacques}{C1}
\indtl@wrindexentry{main}{Frère Jacques}{C2}
\indtl@wrindexentry{main}{Frère Jacques}{C3}
\makeatother
\printindex[main]
\end{document}


Please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is.

As it concern only makeindex and not latex, my exemple was enough. But right. I will provide an other one.

you should probably mention that you are using an internal command from a package that you don't mention in the text (but is in the example now added). makeindex needs some kind of separator but you can use |foo syntax to apply a macro that removes it, eg \def\foo#1|{#1}

To get rid of the C-1--C-3, the -r option for makeindex might be useful. Since the numbers are not page numbers, you probably also need a special .ist.


add the - for makeindex so it can correctly separate the alphabetic and numeric sorting, but apply a macro to remove it later.
\indexentry{Frère Jacques|foo}{C-1}
\indexentry{Frère Jacques|foo}{C-2}
\indexentry{Frère Jacques|foo}{C-3}

produces a .ind
\begin{theindex}

  \item Frère Jacques, \foo{C-1--C-3}

\end{theindex}

so you just need to define \foo to replace C- by C
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1{\xfoo#1C-\relax}
\def\xfoo#1C-#2{\ifx\relax#2\else#1C#2\expandafter\xfoo\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{theindex}

  \item Frère Jacques, \foo{C-1--C-3}

\end{theindex}

\end{document}


Thanks. In my case, it is not always C (it could be any letter). But your pist is a good one. I expected that some .ist setting could help, instead of writing a macro specific.

@Maïeul you can make the macro look for- instead of C- and then check if the following token is - and if so return -- otherwise remove it

FInally I use xstring package (code is clearer with): \newcommand{\removedash}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-}{}}
And add delim_r "\\textendash "  in my .ist. Thanks a lot.

I wouldn't use xstring, latex has far more robust expandable string replacement functions built in, \tl_replace_all for example. @Maïeul  xstring is very much a legacy package not for new code.
